# GUI question : representing large tree on a webpage

Tags: user-interface, tree

I have a tree-like datastructure of some six levels deep, that I would like to represent on a single webpage (can be tabs, trees; ....)

In each level both childnodes and content are possible. Presenting it like a real tree would be not very usable (too big).

I was thinking in the lines of hiding parts of the tree when you drill down and presenting  breadcrumbs or the like to keep you informed as to where you are...

I guess my question boils down to : any ideas? Or example websites of course?

(the question is just about the view, not about the technology, but for the record, I probably use jquery)

Tx!

Comment: You might also be interested in our [UX.SE] site.

Answer (score 0):

I would think a grouped outline would be best where you could simply expand and collapse each group (node) at will.   Think standard outline where parent nodes are larger headings than child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

how i do myself is define a max-height on all tree ul, when some tree node are highter the scrollbars become cumulatives, just style bars to hide them

[image: jtree maxheight ul]

Comment: That doesn't look very usable. I don't see the scrollbars. How am I supposed to know that there are more items under the "prestige" folder? It looks like your layout is just busted.

Comment: so just show them %) hide bars was a choice here. but yes, it can be pretty cool if bar are visible at left of the skeletton line